# iOSOpenDev command line tool build error

Tags: ios, xcode, build-error, command-line-tool

Okay, so i have spent all day searching the web for why this is happening.
I have installed the iOSOpenDev XCode Templates, and I opened a new command line tool project, and its giving me this error:

target specifies product type 'com.apple.product-type.tool', but there's no such product type for the 'iphoneos' platform

Does anyone know how to fix this? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This must be an installation issue. Re-install iOSOpenDev and check if there are errors in its installer log. I had the same problem and resolved it with the following two steps.

```
1) xcode-select must point to the correct xcode location, for example run the following line in Terminal:
$ sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer

2) You must agree xcode license in Terminal
$ sudo xcodebuild -license
$ xcodebuild -license
```

After that, reinstall the tool and it should work.